# Passport.js authentication goes in infinite loop

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, passport.js

I have been trying to build the authentication using PassportJs and MongoDB. I am using PassportJS only to log in. But, while submitting the post request it does not redirect me to the failureRedirect route, nor to the SuccessRedirect one, instead, the web page enters into an endless loop.
The code I have written is -

It has 2 files- app.js and user.js 
App.js file -

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const ejs = require("ejs");
const passport = require('passport');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
require('./db/db')
var fileupload = require('express-fileupload');
const path = require('path');

const app = express();
app.use(fileupload({
  useTempFiles: true
}));
const session = require('express-session');
const mongostore = require('connect-mongo');
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'public')));
// session middle ware
app.use(session({
  secret : 'mysupersecret',
  resave : false,
  saveUninitialized : false,
  store: mongostore.create({
    mongoUrl: process.env.DB,
}),
  cookie : { maxAge : 180 * 60 * 1000 }
}));


app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.render("index");
});

app.use("/admin", require("./routes/admin"));
app.use("/user", require("./routes/user"));
app.use("/task", require("./routes/task"));

// PORT
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(PORT, console.log(`Server started on port ${PORT}`));
```

User.js file -

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const router = express.Router();
const bcrypt = require("bcryptjs");
const passport = require("passport");

const User = require("../models/User");
const Task = require("../models/Task");

var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local');

// var bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
var strategy = new LocalStrategy(function verify(email, password, done) {
  try{
      console.log(email);
  User.findOne({email: email}, function (err, user) {
    console.log(email);
      if (err)
          console.log(err);

      if (!user) {
        console.log("doen exist")
          return done(null, false);
      }

      bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, function (err, isMatch) {
          if (err)
              console.log(err);

          if (isMatch) {
              return done(null, user);
          } else {
            console.log("galat password");
              return done(null, false);
          }
      });
  });
  }catch(err){
    console.log(err);
  }
});

passport.use('epass',strategy);

passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
  done(null, user);
});

passport.deserializeUser((user, done) => {
  done(null, user);
});

// User login
router.get("/login", (req, res) => {
  res.render("user-login");
});


router.post("/login", (req,res) => {
  try{
  passport.authenticate('epass', { failureRedirect: '/user/login' }),
  function(req, res,next) {
    res.redirect('/user');
  }
}catch(err){
  console.log(err);
}
}); 

router.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.render("user")
})

module.exports = router;
```

I have searched everywhere and tried all the available possible solutions but nothing is solving this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`passport.authenticate()` should be used as a middleware, not as a regular function:

```
router.post("/login",
  passport.authenticate('epass', { failureRedirect: '/user/login' }),
  function(req, res,next) {
    res.redirect('/user');
  }
);
```

The way you were using it causes the request to `POST /user/login` to never finish, because it's not sending back any response.

**EDIT**: also, make sure that you either use [the default field names](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-local#available-options) of `username` and `password` for logging in, or add the relevant options to the constructor of `LocalStrategy` to tell it which fields it should be expecting.

Comment: Thank you for responding. I tried this it's working, but the request never enters the passport function like the consoles I have written don't work, and the request is always redirected to the failureRedirect page. Any idea about it?

Comment: It's strange that none of your console.log's are executed, because the `failureRedirect` should only trigger if the strategy fails (or possibly if the strategy doesn't exist). But that would mean it needs to be called first. Are you sure that the strategy name (`epass`) is used correctly (in the code you posted it's correct)?

Comment: Even if I don't use this name epass and call the the strategy in the function itself.. still it gives the same error.

Comment: Yeah, it worked. The issue was that I was using different names. Thank you so much for your help.